# Run asp.net webforms alongside asp.net core project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, webforms, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a cpanel already developed in asp.net webforms all files has .aspx extensions,but our front end web site developed in asp.net core just I need to run cpanel folder like this urls :

> http://localhost:portnumber/cpanel/login.aspx

and front end web site (asp.net core) run with this url

> http://localhost:portnumber/index

it possible run both ? what your suggestion to solve this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with IIS Express. However you can achieve using IIS.

1. Configure your IIS root application pool to ".NET CLR Version: No Manage Code" to run your core application. Example Application Pool to run core Framework App:
   [image]
2. Configure your **cpanel** application as IIS Sub folder (Application) and point it to "Framework Application pool". Example Application Pool to run core App:
   [image]